# How can I set a breakpoint on an empty statement in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Specifically, I want to write a macro that

1) allows me to set a breakpoint
2) does nothing else
3) causes no compiler warnings

```
#define NO_OP   ((void)0)

void main()
{
    bool b = true;
    if (b)
        NO_OP;  // I try to set a breakpoint here, but

}               // it jumps to here (in Visual Studio 2010)
```

I also tried

```
#define NO_OP   (assert(1))             // doesn't work
#define NO_OP   (sizeof(int))           // doesn't work
#define NO_OP   __asm{}                 // doesn't work
#define NO_OP   do {(void)0;} while(0)  // warning: conditional is constant
```

The only thing that works so far is the cringe-worthy

```
#define NO_OP   { int x = 0; x = x; }
```

There has to be a better way.

**EDIT**
Thanks **Blorgbeard**, __asm{ nop } does indeed work. But I just realized that anything with braces is less than perfect (problematic?) because it leaves a useless semi-colon hanging there after it. (Later) I don't know squat about assembler but I tried removing the braces, and voila! There's the answer: __asm nop
Thanks!

**FOR THE CURIOUS**
Here's a slightly less absurd example:

```
string token = GetNextToken();
if (!Ignore(token))
{
    // process token
    DoThis(token);
    DoThat(token);
}
```

This code is complete -- as long as the program works correctly I don't care to know anything about ignored tokens. But at any given time (and without changing the code) I want to make sure that I'm not rejecting good tokens

```
string token = GetNextToken();
if (Ignore(token))
{
    NO_OP; // when desired, set breakpoint here to monitor ignored tokens
}
else
{
    // process token
    DoThis(token);
    DoThat(token);
}
```

Comment: Debuggers can set breakpoints only on memory addresses where some code is that can be executed. Since you don't have something there that is being executed, it can't set a breakpoint there. Maybe using asm volatile noop opcode will do for you, but then again it might be better to tell us what problem you are really trying to solve, since that seems generally like an awkward approach

Comment: @PlasmaHH: this is the problem, I want such a macro, I'm just using an absurd example for brevity.

Comment: Why is `{int x = 0;}` cringe-worthy? I mean, you only put this in your code when _DEBUG is on, right?

Comment: @dog44wgm: "I want such a macro" is not really a problem the solve. You want the macro to solve some problem, and it possibly makes more sense to talk about _that_ problem to provide real solutions.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: that (without the braces) is exactly what I was looking for, can you put it in an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @MrLister Because it's a complex-looking macro that actually does nothing, which makes little sense from a quick glance at the macro itself. Additionally, when using warnings for unused locals, the `x = x` part can't be skipped, which makes it even uglier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An actual no-op instruction:

```
__asm nop
```

Comment: Is this MSVC syntax for assembly? In GCC it looks like it must be `__asm("nop")`.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you can do this:

```
#define BREAKPOINT __asm { int 3; }
```

This will call interrupt 3, which is the breakpoint interrupt.  This will set a breakpoint in your code, which is *compiled* as part of your code.

Now, if you want just some operation that you can set a breakpoint on, which essentially does nothing, besides allowing you to break on that line.  I think you have to compile your code without optimization for one thing, as a NO_OP as you've implemented is likely to be optimized out of the code by an optimizing compiler, with the optimization switches on.

The other point is, that this seems like a very strange thing to do.  From my knowledge, one normally sets a breakpoint on a line of code one wants to look at. See what variable state's are, step one line at a time, etc.  I don't really see how setting a breakpoint on a line of code with essentially no significance in your program, will help you debug anything.

Comment: I think "allows me to set a breakpoint" != "unconditionally executes a breakpoint".

Comment: @SteveJessop if he want's to set a breakpoint, then the breakpoint has to be executed, no?  I don't see the point of allowing one to set a breakpoint, which is then never executed. If the OP is asking that, then I have no answer.

Comment: Usually a debugger allows you to specify which source lines will execute a breakpoint *after* the code is compiled, and for that matter after it has started running. Your proposal places the breakpoints into the executable regardless of what the user of the debugger does. Those are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

On msvc x64 there is an intrinsic for this:

```
__nop();
```

Header file: <intrin.h>

doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/nop?view=msvc-170

Comment: Is there an include file needed for this?

Answer (score 3):

C++03:

```
inline void __dummy_function_for_NO_OP () {}
#define NO_OP __dummy_function_for_NO_OP ()

int main () {
    NO_OP;
}
```

C++11:

```
#define NO_OP [](){}()

int main () {
    NO_OP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `__asm int 3`? Also, are optimizations enabled? That could be the reason for the others failing (actually never tried to break on them).

Answer (score 1):

You could define a global `unsigned int debug_counter`, then your "no-op" macro can be `debug_counter++`. Pretty sure the compiler won't remove that, but to be absolutely sure, put some code somewhere to print the value of the counter.

Answer (score 0):

Define in `myassert.h` and include everywhere in your app (force include in Visual Studio?).

```
// Works cross-platform. No overhead in release builds
#ifdef DEBUG

    // This function may need to be implemented in a cxx module if
    // your compiler optimizes this away in debug builds
    inline bool my_assert_func(const bool b)
    {
        // can set true/false breakpoints as needed
        if (b) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    #define myassert(b) assert(my_assert_func(b))

#else // RELEASE

    // In release builds this is a NOP
    #define myassert(b)    ((void)0)

#endif

#define DEBUG_BREAKPOINT myassert(true)
```

Now you can:

```
string token = GetNextToken();
if (Ignore(token)) 
    DEBUG_BREAKPOINT;
}
else {
    // process token
    DoThis(token);
    DoThat(token);
}
```